# Nhibernate: Is it possible to throw an exception if Save() is called without beginning a transaction

Tags: nhibernate

I was wondering if we can some how extend NHiberate to throw an exception if a piece of code attempted to save an object to a database without beginning a transaction? Since beginning a transaction is a requirement for calling Save() to work properly, I can't see a programmer calling Save() without beginning a transaction in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is not in the exception throwing. It is about keeping us (developers on the project) aware of *what* and *where* we are doing

1) **Project shared approach**. Firstly, explain to the team how the Architecture of application works. All team members should now, that [Unit of Work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx), or [Session per Request](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/03/03/effective-nhibernate-session-management-for-web-apps.aspx) patterns are in place.

2) **The FlushMode**. Secondly, explain the concept of the Session object. `ISession. Save()` or `Update()` is far away from SQL execute `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. What count is the [ISession.Flush()](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing). And (based on the first step) we can decide when that *Flush()* happens.

I would suggest setting the FlushMode to on `Commit` or `None` (with explict call). And then, if a team member would like to Execute any **write** command - one standard place, one common way (used on the project) will guide hin/her.

The call `Session.Flush()` should/will/must be wrapped in a `transaction`.